# Server in Go, redirection to stdout

Tags: networking, tcp, go

How I can implement a server in Go, which sends each incomming line to stdout ?

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    srv, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2000")
    for {
        conn, err := srv.Accept()
        go func(c net.Conn) {

            //How to split here by lines ?

            c.Close()
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

After runing the server with

```
./server
```

And running telnet

```
telnet localhost 2000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
test 123
foobar
```

I want to see on stdout where I started the server:

```
test 123
foobar
```

I know this code lacks error handling, but this is only for clearity to show what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a `net.Conn` is an `io.Reader`, you can wrap it in a `bufio.Reader` and use the `ReadString` method on that type. Your function would become

```
func(c net.Conn) {
    f := bufio.NewReader(c)
    for {
        ln, err := f.ReadString('\n')
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Print(ln)
    }
    c.Close()
}
```

(I'm not sure if stdout is synchronized in Go; it might be cleaner to send the lines on a shared channel that is looped over in a separate goroutine.)

Answer (score 5):

If that's all you want, just copy the socket to stdout.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    srv, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error listening: %v", err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := srv.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error accepting: %v", err)
        }
        go func(c net.Conn) {
            defer c.Close()
            io.Copy(os.Stdout, c)
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

Comment: note that this looks a little bigger than yours because I also added some error handling (though not in the `io.Copy` failure case)